# mount cifs fails but accessing it via File Manager works

Tags: mount, fstab, cifs

I have a NAS (a Western Digital "My Book"). I connected it to my TP-Link Router via USB.
It shows up in the TP-Link Router GUI no problem.

On my Ubuntu 20.04, I connected to it using the File Manager

```
   smb://10.0.0.1/
```

and userid/password as required for TP-Link Router. And that all works just fine. I can create files and folders, and I can delete files and folders, no problem.

I also opened the drive in the "Files" app. And then right clicked on a directory called "backups" and selected "Open In Terminal" and it did. The working directory in that terminal is:

```
$ pwd
/run/user/1000/gvfs/smb-share:server=10.0.0.1,share=g/backups
```

So that part works too. Great.

Now, I'd like to mount the drive (permanently so also need an fstab entry). Searching the 'net says to use:

```
sudo apt install cifs-utils
sudo apt install keyutils
sudo mkdir -p /mybook
sudo mount -t cifs //10.0.0.1/g -o user=xxx,pass=yyy,vers=2.1 /mybook
```

I get:

```
mount error(2): No such file or directory
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs) and kernel log messages (dmesg)
```

dmesg says:

```
[552171.204549] CIFS: Attempting to mount //10.0.0.1/g
[552171.214272] CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -2
```

Searched the 'net and there are a lot of people saying that it works for them. So I am doing something wrong.

Here's some other things I've tried:

- with the File Manager connection set up and with it not connected, same failures
- tried it on Ubuntu 22.04, same failures
- tried vers=2.0, 1.9 and a few others; no errors, no warnings in dmesg, but no files or folders in /mybook
- tried smb://10.0.0.1/g with a warning about "smb", but that's expected, the workaround is to use //10.0.0.1/g
- tried //10.0.0.1 (i.e no "G:" drive), "mount error(22): Invalid argument"
- tried "-v", gives an extra line on the output, no clue why it's "no such file or directory"
- moved the "/mybook" parameter to different places, no joy
- adding trailing slashes "/mybook/" and "//10.0.0.1/g/", no joy.
- added ",domain=WORKGROUP" no joy.
- Also tried "dom=tplink" i.e. the "server name" specified in the tp-link router. no joy.

Any ideas for me to try?

---

Update:
This almost works:

```
sudo mount smb://10.0.0.1/g
sudo ln -s  "/run/user/1000/gvfs/smb-share:server=10.0.0.1,share=g" /mybook2
cd mybook2
```

When I tried to create a file ("touch x.txt") I get:

```
/mybook2$ touch x.txt
touch: setting times of 'x.txt': Permission denied
```

But the x.txt does exist and the time does get set:

```
$ ll x.txt
-rwx------ 1 myuser myuser 0 Jan 19 21:12 x.txt*
```

I tried using sudo. This time the file does NOT get created:

```
rm x.txt
$ sudo touch x.txt
touch: cannot touch 'x.txt': Permission denied
ll x.txt
$ ll x.txt
ls: cannot access 'x.txt': No such file or directory
```

Note that creating a directory works just fine:

```
mkdir x
ll .
```

shows the directory is created and the time is correctly set.

Note that "gedit x.txt" works fine too. No warning about the time.

But rsync gets the same warning:

```
rsync -a ~/Documents/ /mybook2/Documents/
rsync: failed to set times on "/mybook2/Documents/.": Is a directory (21)
rsync: failed to set times on "/mybook2/Documents/Fritzing": Is a directory (21)
etc.
```

---

Update: tried the following:

```
sudo nano /etc/fstab 
//10.0.0.1/g /mybook cifs username=xxx,password=yyy,rw,uid=1000,gid=500,vers=3.0
sudo mount -a
```

got error:

```
mount error(2): No such file or directory
dmesg
[605786.944989] CIFS: Attempting to mount //10.0.0.1/g
[605786.953870] CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -2
```

- tried it with and without "/g"
- tried vers=2.0 and vers=3.0
- created a subdir `mkdir /mybook/g` and tried fstab with '//10.0.0.1/g' and '//10.0.0.1' and '//10.0.0.1/'. All failed in the same way
- tried "/g" and "/G" no joy

---

Update: tried removing vers= option:

current fstab is

```
//10.0.0.1/g /mybook cifs username=xxx,password=yyy,rw,uid=1000,gid=500
```

I get this warning in dmesg:

```
No dialect specified on mount. Default has changed to a more secure dialect, SMB2.1 or later (e.g. SMB3), from CIFS (SMB1). To use the less secure SMB1 dialect to access old servers which do not support SMB3 (or SMB2.1) specify vers=1.0 on mount.
CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -2
```

Note the ubuntu release is a little out of date:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

Comment: @steeldriver the share name is "g" (as in the g: drive). The folder within the drive is "backups"

Comment: this entry in my fstab to connect to a Synology NAS works fine `//192.168.1.117/[share_name] /media/NAS/[mount_point] cifs username=[username],password=[password],rw,uid=1000,gid=500` It is based on the fstab entry I used on a WD MyBookLive which also worked without issue.

Comment: @graham Tried it and it failed in the same way. See above.

Comment: I trust you changed the IP address and the mount point correctly.

Comment: Yup, I believe so: 
"//10.0.0.1/g /mybook cifs username=xxx,password=yyy,rw,uid=1000,gid=500,vers=3.0"

Comment: try removing the `vers=3.0` I don't think thats required now and I certainly don't have it on any of my instances (20.04, 22.04, 23.04, 23.10) and it works well but ISRT when I did include it, it produced an error.

Comment: @graham Updated above. Got a warning, and still failed with rc = -2

Answer (score 0):

What you have added to /etc/fstab seems OK. To mount a directory 'public' of the cifs share of my Synology NAS the /etc/fstab line looks like this:
//192.168.1.122/public /mnt/synology_disk cifs vers=2.0,credentials=/home/xxxx/.smbcredentials,uid=1000,gid=1000,forceuid,forcegid 0 0
The parameters forceuid and forcegid override ownership info of the files in the NAS. The two last positional parameters are set to 0 to disable that the mounted data are handled by the dump command and to disable file system check of the mounted share.

Comment: @kente21 I did. As you can see above, I use Files and named 10.0.0.1/g and it worked just fine. Also in fstab and off the command line I tried 10.0.0.1/ and 10.0.0.1/g 

Anything else I should try?

Comment: okay. The directory on the hard drive is "/mybook" and it is currently empty. The entry in fstab is "/mybook/g". 
' sudo mount -a'
'Couldn't chdir to /mybook/g: No such file or directory'

Comment: Did that already. Did it again just now to double-check:
"//10.0.0.1/g /mybook/xyz cifs username=xxx,password=yyy,rw,uid=1000,gid=500,vers=3.0"
"$ sudo mount -a
Couldn't chdir to /mybook/xyz: No such file or directory"

Comment: Just to doublecheck: /mybook is an existing directory on the Ubuntu computer and g is an existing directory on the NAS?

Comment: you should be able to `cd` to the mount point you have specified in fstab via the terminal but only if it exists. If it doesn't exist, you will get the error found. You have to create it - it doesn't create itself.

Comment: as an aside - you may find [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/13980/345853) in Stack useful towards your understanding of creating mount points and mounting devices in Linux.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).